# Why am getting this CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to check if a person already exists in my database.

```
public Person personExistsInDatabase(String nickname){
    Person personToReturn = null;
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT _id, firstName, lastName FROM " + PERSON_TABLE + " WHERE nickname = '" + nickname + "'";
    Cursor cursor = sqliteDB.rawQuery(query, null);

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        personToReturn = new Person(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    }

    cursor.close();
    sqliteDB.close();

    return personToReturn;
}
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested with a size of 1
```

And I am getting it on this line:

```
personToReturn = new Person(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
```

If the person does not exist, then I add them. If the person does exist, then I update with the new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    personToReturn = new Person(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
}
```

this moves the cursor to the first position and also allows you to check to make sure something is in it

Answer (score 0):

Replace following your code.

```
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){ 
        personToReturn = new Person(
    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("your_column_name")), 
    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("your_column_name")), 
    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("your_column_name"))
     );
    }
```